# Always Listening HTML5 Speech Input

Tags: jquery, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any available jquery plugin that can always listen to speech input without the need of clicking a button? I am familiar with how speech input works but I need my application to be controlled completely handsfree, which is not possible with the current speech implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing would be unlikely to be found as a jQuery plugin. Javascript itself is only just now getting this feature: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/firefox-24-for-android-gets-webrtc-support-by-default/

I'd recommend reading the WebRTC section of MDN's HTML5 documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC

Comment: Is there anyway to extract text from the audio transferred using WebRTC? What I am thinking is an implementation that always listen to a keyword, get the query after the keyword, send it to the server and then return the results.